# Unable to restore bower packages in VS2017 community edition

Tags: git, visual-studio, bower

I am trying to add some bower packages like bootstrap, jquery etc through `"manage bower packages"` option in VS2017 community edition but it always fails and shows the below error msg...

> ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
>   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #128 fatal:
>   unable to access 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git/': Proxy
>   CONNECT aborted

I have tried the following

a) Install git latest version

b) Run the following command in `git bash --- git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

c) Add the following under `tools-->Options-->Web package management-->External web tools . C:\Program Files\Git\bin`

All failed.

Please suggest an answer

Comment: What is git version you have installed?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this myself and after installing [Git For Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and restarting visual studio, restoring bower packages from within visual studio is working again. YMMV